# Is there a most efficient combo to take out Jungle Camps with Lee Sin?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am wondering if, when Jungling with Lee Sin, I should lead in on the Jungle Camps with a certain skill to maximize my clear speed. Is there a certain skill combo to use? Thank You!

Comment: It's Q, Attack, E, Attack, W, Attack, E, attack, W, attack, Q

Comment: @Winter Your passive is triggered for 2 auto attacks, depending on your ability to reset autos and your Attack Speed you can do Q a a q a a w a a e a a w a a e a a (You should do W before E because of the shield + lifesteal, at least pre-6, in order to not take too much damage)

Comment: @oak Yes, your passive is triggered for two auto attacks but utilizing both takes twice as much time. The user asked about efficiency. You also can't cancel autos as lee sin with another auto attack. Also, your second Q active deals damage based on how much missing health the enemy has so utilizing it that early in the combo is a big waste.

Comment: Yes, but dueto using it early you can use it twice, and thus finishing off with the Q rather than having to still auto and take more damage (and time)

Comment: You shouldn't take that long to clear camps where you get two q's off. Also, that means it's on CD which reduces your mobility when getting to the next camp. The combos depend on damage and how fast you can clear normally, but the q w e w e with at least one auto in between is the general pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Since your passive refunds energy always make sure that you AA twice before using another ability. Below is the rotation I usually take.

**W1 >> AA*2 >> W2 >> AA*2 >> Q1 >> AA*2 >> Q2 >> AA*2 >> E1**

I always find it better to start with W because the jungle camps hit hard early and the sustain from your second combo'd with smite helps you stay alive. Do not use the second E because it does no damage and doesn't reduce the attack speed of enemies any more making the spell useless while clearing. never start with Q because your second Q is an execution spell. It will deal more damage based on how much health the enemy is missing. Using it second allows you to use the spell vamp from the second W.

I hope this helps

Jaimin

*Source: I am a jungle main and have been playing since Season 3.*

Answer (score 0):

It's super dependent on your items/level/in game time, *but* I usually do this to get started (as a gold/plat lee sin main, know somewhat what I'm doing but I'm no god):

Have 11% AS in your runes for this to work properly.

Start machete and pots.

- Start Krugs, start W. Not as much damage but oh well you have a leash and it lets you finish with full hp. Smite on Krugs for the stun. Don't save your smite unless you think they'll invade.
- Take E next, go kill red with W >> aa*2 >> W aa*2 >> E aa*2 >> E aa*2 (repeat as needed). Kill the smalls first, save your 5th auto for stun proc (from krugs smite) for the elder. Use a pot if needed (depends on leash + how efficient you are).
- Skip raptors and wolves, get to your blue. Over the wall with your trinket ward and W. Again, smalls first but stun the big guy.
- Once that's done, get your q, you definitely still have your krugs smite passive, kill the gromp asap (aa E aa W aa W aa smite Q aa aa Q). This should heal you as long as you smite during your 2nd W and you get krugs stun proc and shield up separately to block the most damage.
- Use potions if needed for full hp (shouldn't be a problem), as you head to gank top. If that wouldn't go well, invade their jg or gank mid. You should have your second trinket ward, use it as part of your gank or use it to get vision in enemy jg, user discretion. It also helps if you inform your top laner that you plan on a gank between 3:10 and 3:30 game time so he doesn't push.

Lee sin has strong ganks even before 6, and can invade very well too. Make use of this. As soon as you can, buy warriors. Trackers, challenging smite, and blue smite are all good. I like blue for the slow, challenging does more damage though, and trackers is fantastic for sight, and proc'ing your w. Build after that is too dependent on team comp, scores, enemy builds, etc for me to lay out here. Lee Sin is a very versatile champ, and can function well within many many build paths.

Keep jg'ing with similar patterns on your abilities. Here are some quick tips:

- 2nd Q proc does more damage on missing hp, it's an execute move.
- Your 2nd W proc heals based on damage dealt, use your E and Q during it if at all possible
- It's often faster (and still energy efficient as the first attack restores double the energy as the second) to just do one aa between abilities.
- Don't skip the second E proc on a long jg fight, it gets you the attack speed again, and restores the same amount of energy as cost.
- Q's and W's to get across walls faster. Lee sin isn't the fastest clearer of camps, but he traverses the jungle incredibly quickly which makes up for some current lack of clear speed.
- IF you feel you need it (I used to but no longer do), it can be kind of a safeguard (pun intended) to get your W to lvl 2 before maxing Q/E.
- Lee Sin is fantastic at stealing buffs and dragons/barons, due to his Q being an execute, his abilities granting him sight, and his excellent mobility both in and out of the camp (q in w out).

Jaimin's post is also good, I just thought I'd help out with a bit more detail. You also don't have to always get off your 2nd aa between, it's not always faster, but that is a good rule. Watch streamers do it to get a feel, and just play it to get a feel. Try different things yourself too, try even the downvoted post's and commenter's methods. They may not be the best, but it's good to learn why yourself.

One last thing: Post 11, or when not being very energy efficient (last camp before a gank, last camp before a back, who knows why but there are many good reasons) Winter's comment is 100% the way to go, but you may not even need the W or 2nd E proc.

Answer (score -2):

Your passive allows you to gain extra life steal and attack speed for the next 2 autos after using an ability. Early on (disregarding sustain, just clear speed) the optimal combo would be
Q1 > 2 Autos > E1 > 2 Autos > W1 > 2 Autos > W2 > 2 Autos
The 1 or 2 after an ability being the first or second proc. It is useless to use your 2nd E proc as the minions will not be moving very much anyway.

Once this combo clears the camp before your second W proc, or you have near maxed your Q. It may be quicker to Q1 > 2 Autos > Q2 > 2 Autos to clear the camp instead. It depends on your build, level, etc.